# How to execute all lines in try block before it moves to catch?

Tags: java, try-catch, token

I have to read a file in try block and later print it out. While the print method is working, the program is not running the method. How do I solve this? I can't keep it in the while loop.

Lexer.java

```
private boolean atEOF = false;
private SourceReader source;

public static void main(String args[]) {
  Token token;
    
  try {
    Lexer lex = new Lexer(args[0]);

    while(!(lex.atEOF)) {
      token = lex.nextToken(); 
    }
  
  lex.source.printVec(); // WANT TO EXECUTE THIS METHOD

 
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("usage: java lexer.Lexer filename.x"); 
      System.exit(-1);
  } 
}
```

SourceReader.java

```
public void printVec() {

  System.out.println("in the program");

  for (String l : progVec) {
    System.out.println(l);
  }
}
```

How do I run `printVec()` after the `while` loop in Lexer.java?

Comment: If the exception is thrown then it won't be called and it must be like that. If exception is not thrown and if method is still not called, then you must be stuck into infinite loop. There's no other ways.

Comment: What happens instead? Do you get an exception? What happens when you run the code under the debugger and step through it? Also, why do you just get all the tokens and discard them? Did you intend to do something with them? Maybe that part isn't done yet, but I imagine `progVec` is going to be empty.

Comment: Something in your program is throwing an exception before you get to that line. You need to find out what's wrong and fix it. Remove your `catch` block -- it is catching every exception and hiding them from you.

Answer (score -1):

I would simply declare the Lexer outside of the try-catch block then put the required Function at the first line of the catch part too.

```
Lexer lex;  
try {
  lex = new Lexer(args[0]);

  while(!(lex.atEOF)) {
    token = lex.nextToken(); 
  }
  lex.source.printVec(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
  lex.source.printVec();
  //... rest of code
}
```

Comment: lex is not initialized so throwing an error.

Comment: I think you need to go deep inside the lexer class and catch the error there and do the required modification the way you need to.